# libcamera-hello error in Raspberry pi bullseye

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have installed Raspbian Bullseye (64 bit) recently and when I tried to run
`libcamera-hello`, I am getting this error:

```
libcamera-hello: error while loading shared libraries: libcamera_app.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to mitigate this error? Thank you!

Comment: libcamera_app.so is there at all?  What does the command "file libcamera_app.so" output?

Comment: And what does the command "ldd libcamera-hello" output

Comment: It gives me: libcamera_app.so: cannot open `libcamera_app.so' (No such file or directory)
And for ldd: ldd: ./libcamera-hello: No such file or directory

Comment: "file libcamera-hello"?

Comment: Yup, the same thing: libcamera-hello: cannot open `libcamera-hello' (No such file or directory)

Comment: Maybe you are confused by directories?  These commands must be executed while in the directory where these files are located.

Comment: Or specify full paths to files

Comment: Ohh ok. How do i know where this file is located?

Comment: find / -name libcamera_app.so

Comment: Got it! This is what I get: /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcamera_app.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=4c67be7e218253d628f84d306754876ac30e81d1, not stripped

Comment: And there are two files apparantly: /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcamera_app.so, 
/usr/lib/libcamera_app.so

Comment: Try "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/" or move .so to /usr/lib.

Comment: "file /usr/lib/libcamera_app.so"?

Comment: So I copy pasted that line and ran it. Then when I ran libcamera-hello, it gave me this error: ERROR: the system appears to be configured for the legacy camera stack

Comment: This is another error, we solved the first one.  It's better to ask a new error in a new question.  The library /usr/lib/libcamera_app.so cause an error, it is better to remove it.

Comment: I actually restarted my pi and when I run libcamera-hello, I get the same error as original: libcamera-hello: error while loading shared libraries: libcamera_app.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory and when I run  file /usr/lib/libcamera_app.so, it gives me /usr/lib/libcamera_app.so: broken symbolic link to /usr/local/lib/libcamera_app.so

Comment: And I also deleted the /usr/lib/libcamera_app.so. So when I find for the .so file, I only get 1 file now: /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcamera_app.so. And when I did the export line and run libcamera-hello, i get the legacy error but when I do file /usr/lib/libcamera_app.so, it says there is no file like that.

Comment: "file /usr/lib/libcamera_app.so"?

Comment: Gives: /usr/lib/libcamera_app.so: cannot open `/usr/lib/libcamera_app.so' (No such file or directory)

Comment: A bad symlink interferes with the library loader.  It shouldn't exist, or it should be correct.

Comment: So what can i do now? Should I pip install the libcamera?